# "Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be faster)"... every time

Tags: ubuntu, gradle, gradle-daemon

I use Gradle 2.10 on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

I was getting told "*This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon*" so I created a `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file containing  `org.gradle.daemon=true`.

Result: Every time I run `./gradlew build`, I am now told:

```
Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be faster).
```

... every single time. And the build does not get faster and faster: it always takes about 10 seconds. If I run the build 3 times in a row, it outputs the message above 3 times, and though I am well below Gradle's [3 hours of inactivity automatic shutdown](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:how_can_i_stop_a_daemon).

How to fix this and make the daemon survive for a longer time?

Answer (score 13):

In the root of the project create `gradle.properties` with

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

It keeps the instance of gradle up and running in the background even after your build finishes.

It doesn't work for CI environment (travis ci for example) if your environment recreated every build.

Also: [Gradle will kill any Daemon that has been idle for 3 hours or more, so you don’t have to worry about cleaning them up manually.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html)

There are no configs in default gradle for increase daemon uptime.

Answer (score -1):

Upgrading to Gradle 4.0.1 (and presumably later versions) solves the problem.

You can upgrade Gradle by using your packaging system or downloading binaries at https://gradle.org/install/

Comment: I'm on Gradle 4.4.1 and still seeing this.